# How to resize my root partition with unallocated space with Home and Swap directory in between

Tags: unallocated, merge

[image: Gparted output]
 how to merge my root partition with unallocated space with Home and Swap directory in between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **move** sda8 all the way right
- **move** sda7 all the way right
- **resize** the right side of sda6 all the way right
- click the Apply icon

Comment: Thanks very much Mr. @heynnema for the quick and helpful answer. I was able to resize and move the partition ask per your instruction using the Live Boot USB.  Very Appreciated